# What is this business jet?

Tags: aircraft-identification, private-jets

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

It could be a Learjet, but I can't find a match.

Comment: interesting. I thought it might be a Dassault Falcon, but can't find a match in that range.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The tail is quite unique. I thought about Embraer Phenom, Hondajet, and Cessna Citation, but it is none of these.

I believe that your images are showing a **[British Aerospace 125](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Aerospace_125)** (aka Hawker 800/1000, or DH125 Jet Dragon). They were produced from 1977 to 2013, and most of them have been in service for the air forces of Japan, Brazil, and Saudi Arabia.

[image]
<sup>Source: [wikimedia.org](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:BAe125_aircraft_from_a_flight_of_32_(The_Royal)_Squadron_MOD_45147916_(cropped).jpg)</sup>

Comment: Yes, that looks like one! You made my day bogl, thank you very much.

Comment: Not really, was looking through some old Miami Vice episodes and trying to figure out what plane was being used :) Thank you for taking your time and answering bogl :)

Comment: @Chris Miami Vice would have been a good piece of information to include - at least dates the craft to active service in the mid-late 1980s.